# Getting an Error 3050 Could not Lock File

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, recordset

I have a Problem with my multiuser Access database. I try to produce 2 series of presentations, which are both using the same database. The error occurs completely randomly between 1 and 240 produced presentations. I open the database in read-only ... I get the 3050 error anyway ... The way I connect to the database is like this: I have a frontend with query and a backend with tables. I always connect to the frontend and the queries with following code:

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc, False, True)

SQL = "SELECT *   From qry_xxxxx"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

Do Until rs.EOF = True

i = i + 1

xxx(i, 1) = rs!xxx
xxx(i, 2) = rs!xxx


rs.MoveNext ' nächstes RecordSet laden
Loop

rs.Close
db.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Any idea why I get a "Could not Lock Database" error, even when I am opening the database in read-only modus?

My code to write some data in the database (relevant for another program) is not used in this context at all

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc2, False, False)

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, , dbOptimistic)
```

Will it be possible to run the database with multiple users? I already tested it and the parallel writing works fine ... just the Error 3050 occurs randomly ???

Thank you guys a Lot I am really clueless right now.
Fabian

Comment: ```The way I connect to the database is like this: I have a frontend with query and a backend with tables. I always connect to the frontend and the queries with following code``` If i understand this correctly you are in the backend accessing the front end. You want the backend on a server locations and all users would have a local front end, then you can have multiple users in the same database.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. Actually i am Working in a Tool with UserForm which is based on excel. The Frontend is on the Server too, i have 300 Users so its kind of difficult to spread the FE local? Anyways i tested a Multiuser Prozess and they wrote in the Database in the same table at the same time over the same frontend and it worked...
Anyways the First way i Connect in Tool 1 is always as read only and in the Same Tool i get the error 3050 .. i am closing all connection after i use it ...